# .subscribe(-) vs .map(-).subscribe() in reactive Java

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm reading the project reactor documentation on transforming data using the [transforming operators](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#which.values) on Mono and Flux. But I can help asking the question..

What's the difference between doing logic in the `.map()` function then calling subscribe vs doing it all in the `.subscribe()` function?

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67619515/difference-between-flux-subscribeconsumer-super-t-consumer-and-flux-doonne), subscribe is described as the

> final consumer and usually called by your framework ... rather than by user code.

But [subscribe()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe--) seems to be a used quite frequently in tutorials and in code I come across. Here is simple example.

```
// example using map
Mono.just("book1").map(book -> {
    bookService.rentOut(book);
    return book;
}).subscribe();


// example using subscribe
Mono.just("book2").subscribe(book -> {
    bookService.rentOut(book);
});
```

And if bookService **returns an error** the question still remains, handle in the `map()` or use `subscribe(consumer, errorConsumer)`.

Comment: If you use .map(), you can pass around the Mono with the mapping function "built-in".

Answer (score 0):

The [`map()` operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is used to convert a produced value from one type to a different type based on the given [`Function<T, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) argument.

The [`subscribe()` method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#subscribe-java.util.function.Consumer-) will "activate" the observable and will receive the produced values in its [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) method. This is also the last step in your reactive programming chain for this particular observable since this method is not returning a `Mono<T>` instance anymore but instead a `Disposable` instance, which will be used for terminating the subscription.

`Subscribe()` is "used quite frequently in tutorials" as you stated because it is required to "activate" the observable/subscription, otherwise nothing will happen. All the operators before are for "configuration" like "when value X is produced, convert it to Y, throttle the produced values, build them together in chunks, filter the chunks based on some condition, switch to a different thread, etc…". You can build a chain of operators in which the produced values passes through. However this is just "configuration" and nothing will happen unless you subscribe to it.